# How to retrieve Outlook.AddressEntry object from String with the mailbox address?

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I have as given String for example john@doe.com and I have to set up this as outgoing mailbox in a MailItem using the Sender setter in a C# VSTO project.

This is my actual code (I let the full qualified name to indicate what I mean with MailItem):

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem) Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
mailItem.Subject = "Order #1";
mailItem.To = "orderbot@doe.com";
mailItem.Sender = (Here has to be the EntryAddress)
mailItem.Display(false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `Namespace.CreateRecipient` / `Recipient.Resolve` / use `Recipient.AddressEntry`.

Why not set the `MailItem.SentOnBehalfOfName` property?

Comment: I found the answer. The correct answer is to set mailItem.SendUsingAccount with any Account from Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.Accounts which matches.

Gonna still give you the points.